# what is wrong with this line?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter and i am stuck trying to figure out what is going wrong on this line

here is my controller

```
class Product extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->model('product_model');
        $data['products'] = $this->product_model->get_all_products();
        $this->load->view('all_products', $data); 

    }
}
```

here is my model

```
class Product_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_all_products(){
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            } 
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Product::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 50
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Users/matt/Sites/ci/application/models/product_model.php on line 9el.php on line 6
```

the error is on this line

```
$query = $this->db->get('products');
```

why is it failing the codeigniter documentation describes it that way...i have a products table also

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter model error: Undefined property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440839/codeigniter-model-error-undefined-property)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

in application/config/autoload.php

Comment: You should accept his answer then if it is solved. FYI unless you omitted it for speed above you are missing your constructs.

Comment: @BrandonS: constructors aren't required.

Comment: @treeface: oh I know and i understand that this may not be his code exactly but if it was i wanted to point out that the use of a constructor is helpful and should be a normal part of your OOP process besides constructors are a efficient way to initialize objects. I just feel that most people in PHP are using selected parts of OOP standards that benefit them and leave out others and in my opinion constructors are a vital part of oop that shouldn't be left out. But you were right in the fact that the use of a construct is not required and i should have worded my comment to reflect that.

Comment: @BrandonS: I'm left wondering a bit what benefit can be gained by an empty constructor, or how it is best OOP practice to have one just for the sake of having one. I'm also a little curious what you mean by "constructors are a efficient way to initialize objects". Sure...if you have something to do in a constructor (like loading a library specific to that controller or model when you don't want to autoload it), but otherwise..?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check two things
1- you are not missing constructor

```
class Product_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

2- you have loaded database library. Go to **application/config/autoload.php** and add 'database' in autoload libraries.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Answer (score 0):

you must go to autoload and replace `$autoload['libraries']` with this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation');`