# codeigniter core/model.php undefined property

Tags: codeigniter

I have never touched the model.php file, however I am getting this error. Jobprocess is my controller and `$lastname` is a variable assigned correctly within it. I have no idea why this error is coming up.  This is using codeigniter framework

```
Message: Undefined property: Jobprocess::$lastname

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 50
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter model error: Undefined property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440839/codeigniter-model-error-undefined-property)

Comment: do you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make sure to autoload model on **application/config/autoload.php** at line 56.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Second, make sure that the name of php file is lowercase (mymodel.php)
and finally, make sure to capitalize the first letter of your model class name

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model{}
```

***Codeigniter Version 3** - Models must have a file name that begins with a capital letter: 
"Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class." https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Answer (score 2):

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
in autoload.php
I was doing the nettuts session on codeigniter and spent two hours and n number of cigerrates before I finally figured it out.

Comment: n number of cigarrates is not a recommended solution.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer loading the Database within the Model class we write, than Auto-loading it via the Config files. 
Like follows:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class fruits_model extends CI_Model {

private $fruits_table;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();

    $this->fruits_table = 'fruits';
}
```

Add the following line,

```
$this->load->database();
```

Within the Model's constructer.

Cheers!