# codeigniter can't load $db active record in one controller but yes in another controller

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have a Message controller that use Message_model to use the database by active record.
Everything is OK.

Message_model code

```
function send_message($data) {
        $this->db->insert($this->table_name, $data);
        $num = $this->db->affected_rows();
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

But in another controller(User controller) that use the Message_model.
It give me

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: Maxdoodle::$db</p>
<p>Filename: core/Model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 51</p>
```

I've setup the default active record in database.php
Because I can use it in Message controller as mention before.

CodeIgniter version:2.1.1

Comment: Have you loaded the model in that controller also...???

Comment: sounds like you forgot to call parent constructor in your Maxdoodle model?

Comment: Gautam3164 Yes.I've loaded the model.

Comment: Can you post the code of both controllers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter model error: Undefined property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440839/codeigniter-model-error-undefined-property)

Comment: Hi @Magic, if below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your database library is not loaded try auto load :

```
 $autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);
```