# codeigniter calendar class error message

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, calendar

I use codeigniter calendar class and i am trying to display all reservations for the current month. In the field where the day is, I may have more than one result,and I would like to display them coma separated.

However, I get the following error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$reservationID
Filename: models/reservationcalendarmodel.php
Line Number: 81

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$reservationArrivalDate
Filename: models/reservationcalendarmodel.php
Line Number: 81
```

Error is displayed 10 times ( i expect 9 records from the database)

Here is the (relevant) code from the model:

```
function getReservations($year,$month) {
    $currentHotelUser = $this->session->userdata('currentHotelUser');
    $query = $this->db->query(
       "SELECT r.*
        FROM room r
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT rr.roomID, re.reservationID,re.reservationArrivalDate 
        FROM reservationroom rr 
        LEFT JOIN reservation re ON re.reservationID = rr.reservationID
        WHERE re.reservationArrivalDate LIKE('".$year."-".$month."-%'))  
        sq ON sq.roomID = r.roomID
        WHERE r.hotelID = ".$currentHotelUser['hotelID']." 
        AND sq.reservationID IS NOT NULL             
    ");

    $cal_data = array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        // BELLOW IS THE LINE 81 WHERE THE ERROR IS 
        $cal_data[substr($row->reservationArrivalDate,8,2)]= $row->reservationID; 
    }
    return $cal_data;
}    

function generate($year,$month) {
    $cal_data = $this->getReservations($year, $month);
    $this->load->library('calendar', $this->conf);
    return $this->calendar->generate($year,$month,$cal_data);    
}
```

Here is the (relevant) code from the controller:

```
$this->load->model('ReservationCalendarModel');
$data['calendar'] = $this->ReservationCalendarModel->generate($year,$month);
```

Here is the (relevant) code from the view:

```
echo $calendar;
```

Did anyone know why do I get the above error?

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440839/codeigniter-model-error-undefined-property

Comment: I have the following: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');

Comment: Add `print_r($row)` before the offending line. Post the results.

Comment: There are still people using codeigniter in 2014 O.o

Comment: ...and more than you'd think...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you query results not having reservationID and reservationArrivalDate. That is the reason, while looping through you are getting this error. Add these two columns in your main select query

```
"SELECT r.*, sq.roomID, sq.reservationId
        FROM room r
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT rr.roomID, re.reservationID,re.reservationArrivalDate 
        FROM reservationroom rr 
        LEFT JOIN reservation re ON re.reservationID = rr.reservationID
        WHERE re.reservationArrivalDate LIKE('".$year."-".$month."-%'))  
        sq ON sq.roomID = r.roomID
        WHERE r.hotelID = ".$currentHotelUser['hotelID']." 
        AND sq.reservationID IS NOT NULL             
    "
```