# Pass data to model from controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am getting data from view using post method ie., in $data variable
and I need pass this  i.e, $data to model I have tried like below but it is showing like A **PHP**

> Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message:  Undefined property:
>   Post::$data Filename: core/Model.php Line Number: 77

Below is mycode:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Mohan
    [email] => mohan@gmail.com
    [phone] => 9739764966
    [location] => TEST
    [website] => 192.168.1.156
    [useragent] => Chrome
    [ipaddress] => 192.168.1.23
    [desc] => Bengaluru
    [captcha] => 20701449
    [captcha_word] => 20701449
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

controller:

```
public function postEnquiry()
{
    $data = $this->input->post();
    // echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
    $this->load->model('Enquiry');
    $result = $this->Enquiry->sendenquiry($data);
    if($result){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Sent Successfully');
        redirect(ROOT_PATH."/form");
    }

}
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Enquiry extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function sendenquiry($data)
    {
        print_r($data);die;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: what kind of error did you get?

Comment: @JayZamsol Like 'A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Post::$data Filename: core/Model.php Line Number: 77'

Comment: I got it what is the issue now its working fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must load the db library first in **autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

First, you must define the variable then assign post values to variable and pass the arguments,

```
public function postEnquiry()
{
    $this->load->model('Enquiry');
    $data = array();
    $data = $this->input->post();       
    $result = $this->Enquiry->sendenquiry($data);
    if($result){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Sent Successfully');
        redirect(ROOT_PATH."/form");
    }
}

(OR)

// You can get post values from model directly
// 1.Controller
public function postEnquiry()
{
    $this->load->model('Enquiry');
    $result = $this->Enquiry->sendenquiry();
    if($result){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Sent Successfully');
        redirect(ROOT_PATH."/form");
    }
}

// 2.Model
public function sendenquiry()
{
  echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->input->post()); echo '</pre>'; //post values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your database library in autoload.php:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Also, load your model in the constructor or inside your function like this:

```
$this->load->model('User');
```

Take a look to a similar question here [codeigniter model error: Undefined property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440839/codeigniter-model-error-undefined-property)

Hope it helps.